# React) router add but nothing to show on browser

Tags: reactjs, router

i just edited three pages as below.. but can't see anything on the webpage
i saw that there's react-router-dom in the json file
i tried to install router dom several times
and the webbrowser console says 'typeerror'

// index.jsx //

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';

import './index.css';
import ItemList from './components/itemList/ItemList';
import NewPage from './pages/NewPage'
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path:'/',
    element: <ItemList />,
    errorElement: <NotFound />,
    children: [
      { index: true, path: '/', element: <ItemList />},
      { path: '/newpage', element: <NewPage />},
    ],
  }
])

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router}></RouterProvider>;
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

// App.js //

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/navbar/Navbar'
import ItemList from './components/itemList/ItemList';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <ItemList />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

// Navbar.jsx//

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <section>
      <Link to="/newpage">
        <h1>Create Box</h1>
      </Link>
    </section>
  );
}
```

npm install react-hook-form